# Limit is $0$ uniformly for fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f,g$ be periodic functions and $p>1$ such that,

$$
f\in L^p((-\pi,\pi)), g\in L^q((-\pi,\pi))
$$
Consider the function
$$
h(x,t) = f(x+t)g(t)
$$
prove that $h$ is measurable. Consider

$$
c_n(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x+t)g(t)e^{-int}\;dt
$$
Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} = 0$ uniformly for $x\in \mathbb(R)$

Any suggestions for proving the limit is $0$ uniformly??

Comment: Did you mean $1/p+1/q = 1$ ? Otherwise the integral doesn't have to converge. $|c_n(x)| \le \|f(x+.) g\|_{L^1(-\pi,\pi)}$.

Comment: Yes. Your observation about p and q is correct. But using your recommendation I just can prove using holder inequality that this term is bounded independently of n, but doesn’t prove it goes to 0.

Comment: Riemann-Lebesgue lemma : you need to approximate $h_x = f(x+.) g$ by a sequence of $C^1$ functions $h_{x,n}$, whose decay of Fourier coefficients is well understood

Comment: @reuns It seems to me that if you do that, you'll get an estimate depending on the  derivative of the approximant, but why should that be under control?

Comment: @zhw. I'd say we can show the continuity (thus uniform) in $x,\epsilon$ of  $h_{x,\epsilon} = h_x \ast \phi_\epsilon$ and hence of $\widehat{h_{x,\epsilon}}(n)$. But maybe you meant I should have written piecewise $C^1$ instead of $C^1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\Lambda_n$ be defined on $L^1$ by the formula

$$\Lambda_n (h) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi h(t)e^{-int}\,dt.$$

Then $\{\Lambda_n\}$ is easily seen to be equicontinuous. By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, $\Lambda_n \to 0$ pointwise on $L^1.$ Apply Arzela-Ascoli to see $\Lambda_n \to 0$ uniformly on compact subsets of $L^1.$ Then show the functions $f(x+t)g(t), x\in [-\pi,\pi],$ form a compact subset of $L^1.$